# Javascript How to set scrolled items stop in the middle position

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the demo in jsfiddle, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ato0mf7u/3/)

What I want is let the scrolled items('one ', 'two', 'three', '4', '5', '6', '7') automatically scroll up like the demo showed, and stop when it's in the middle position.

Here is the place in my demo code for setting position.

```
if ((x == 0) || (x % 35== 0)) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        i.top = x + 'px';
    }, 1000);
} else {
    i.top = x + 'px';
}
```

The reason why I set 35 is because I found that the scrolled items are approximately in the middle position when it equals to 0, -35,-70,-105,.... But when I console all x, I found that the value of x is between (31, -251). Do you know how to find the exact position when each items are in the middle of position? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you give a height to `#myscrollerin p` and put `one` in a `<p>` tag as well, then do your math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I found: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ato0mf7u/7/)

**The changes were**

**1)** Add this in your css:

```
#myscroller p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

**2)** Change the value of your variable `i` at line 4 to `0`, otherwise it won't add the first value of your array inside a `<p>` tag

**3)** Change the value of your variable `txt`at line 10 to `''`, an empty string

**4)** This `i.top = x + 'px';` need to be always called, otherwise your scroller will be 1px late when it stops

**5)** Since your line-height is `30px` your scroller will stop when `x % 30` is true

**NOTE:** If you want to change your line-height, its value needs to be the same as your `#myscroller` height and the same as the value you check at `x % 30`